# Efficiently sorting array items during insertion

Tags: swift, sorting

I have an array of sections:

```
struct Section {
    let title: String
    var items: [Item]
}
```

Which contains a list of items:

```
struct Item {
    let title: String
}
```

I'd like to populate this with an unknown amount of items, and sort the data as efficiently as possible. I fetch the data from a remote source, and parse the data as it comes in. I can't know if the data being sent is sorted or not, so blindly appending to a `Section` list may not work here.

I'd like the data to be shown to the user as soon as it comes in (in batches), so I can't wait until the end of the fetch operation to perform sorting. For examples sake, lets assume I'm getting the section by:

```
let item = Item(title: "Foo")
let sectionTitle = item.characters.first!
if let section = sections.filter({ $0.title == String(sectionTitle) }) {
  // find
} else {
  // create
}
```

My initial idea, once I've figured out the correct `Section`, loop through the `Section` items until `sectionItem.title > item.title`, then that becomes the insertion point:

```
var insertionPoint = 0
for (i, val) in array.enumerated() {
    insertionPoint = i
    if val.title > item.title { break }
}

section.items.insert(item, at: insertionPoint)
```

This does seem inefficient once the `Section` has many `Item` objects. Is there a more appropriate method?

My only other thought would be to keep track of `Section` items that were touched in this batch, then running `section.items.sort()` at the end of each batch operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each batch of items:

1. Add each item to a temp array for a section.
2. Sort each temp array.
3. Merge the sorted temp array with the already sorted array for the section.  Merging two sorted arrays is a very efficient operation.

Comment: That looks like it could work well, do you know what Swift's `sort()` method uses under the hood?

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know the details of Swift's `sort`.